# Order objects in array based on values of two attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of N objects and each object has the following fields:

```
{
  id: 'an id',
  description: 'a description',
  isUser: true/false
}
```

I need to order that array based on two things:

Firstly, if the description includes either 'dog', 'cat' or 'animal', it should have sooner position in the array.
Secondly, if the value `isUser` is `false`, it should also have a sooner position in the array.

I have notice that the `sort` function doesn't help when you want to prioritize by value of different attributes, so I am wondering what is the best way to do this in Javascript (or Lodash, which I am also using: https://lodash.com/)

Comment: please add some data for sorting and the wanted order.

Comment: What do you mean by sooner position? do you want object with properties `isUser: false` and `description: 'dog'/'cat' or 'animal'` to appear before the rest other elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the wanted top string are in the description and move these item to top, as well as `false` values of `isUser`.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, description: 'cat', isUser: false }, { id: 5, description: 'dog', isUser: true }, { id: 6, description: 'flower', isUser: true }, { id: 7, description: 'cat', isUser: true }, { id: 2, description: 'animal', isUser: false }, { id: 3, description: 'tree', isUser: false }, { id: 4, description: 'dog', isUser: false }];
  
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var top = ['dog', 'cat', 'animal'];
    return top.includes(b.description) - top.includes(a.description) || a.isUser - b.isUser;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina one question, why in the includes case you put B description first, and when doing the `isUser` you put the A first? So, why not do: ```return top.includes(b.description) - top.includes(a.description) || b.isUser - a.isUser;```?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = [{
  id: 'an id',
  description: 'a description dog',
  isUser: false
},{
  id: 'an id 2',
  description: 'a description animal',
  isUser: true
},{
  id: 'an id 3',
  description: 'a description',
  isUser: true
},{
  id: 'an id 4',
  description: 'a description',
  isUser: false
}]

function sort(arr){
  return arr.sort(a=> !(a.description.includes('dog')||a.description.includes('cat')||a.description.includes('animal') || !a.isUser))
}

console.log(sort(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a compareFunction to sort method of array, so the `sort` function should help. Example:

```
yourArray.sort( function(a, b) {
    if ( !a.isUser || a.description == 'animal')  return -1;
    return 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you question is to rearrange the existing array based on the properties and conditions given.

```
// grouping on basis of "description" 

const animalGrp = _.groupBy(array, (t) => _.includes(t.description, 'dog') || _.includes(t.description, 'cat') || _.includes(t.description, 'animal') );

// grouping on basis of "isUser" 
const userGrp = _.groupBy(animalGrp.false, 'isUser');

// final output
const result = [...animalGrp.true, ...userGrp.true, ...userGrp.false]
```